# When are targets chosen in Final Fantasy TCG?

Tags: final-fantasy-tcg

In the FAQ, some cards, like Hades (1-046U ハーデス) mention a need to have valid targets when the card is used. This entry also implies that some targets may become invalid before resolution time. This implies that targets are chosen at cast time. However, in the official rules, the only place where choosing a target seems to be mentioned deals with thing happening at resolution time (11.11.4.1.1.). Since there's no special rules mentioning it, this implies that choosing a target is just part of the effect and so is done at resolution time.

I don't know how to resolve this. When is the choosing of a target supposed to take place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was explained in [a tweet from the developer](http://bit.ly/113qdgS):

> #### Question
>
> 「選ぶ」ある召喚獣やアビリティがあります。使う時に選ぶと思うが11.11.4.1.1.以外「選ぶ」を特別扱うルールは見つけることができないので結果の一部として解決時に選ぶべきも思われます。どっちが正しいですか。ルールにその答えがいたならその番号も教えてください。
>
> There is a summon and abilities that "choose". Although 11.11.4.1.1. Other than "choose" a special treat rules also seems to choose at the time of resolution as part of the result because it can not find think that choosing when to use. Which is correct? Please also tell me the number if the answer was in the rules. <sup><sub>([Auto-translated through Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/%E3%80%8C%E9%81%B8%E3%81%B6%E3%80%8D%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B%E5%8F%AC%E5%96%9A%E7%8D%A3%E3%82%84%E3%82%A2%E3%83%93%E3%83%AA%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%81%8C%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%80%82%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%86%E6%99%82%E3%81%AB%E9%81%B8%E3%81%B6%E3%81%A8%E6%80%9D%E3%81%86%E3%81%8C11.11.4.1.1.%E4%BB%A5%E5%A4%96%E3%80%8C%E9%81%B8%E3%81%B6%E3%80%8D%E3%82%92%E7%89%B9%E5%88%A5%E6%89%B1%E3%81%86%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AF%E8%A6%8B%E3%81%A4%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7%E7%B5%90%E6%9E%9C%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%80%E9%83%A8%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E8%A7%A3%E6%B1%BA%E6%99%82%E3%81%AB%E9%81%B8%E3%81%B6%E3%81%B9%E3%81%8D%E3%82%82%E6%80%9D%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8C%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%80%82%E3%81%A9%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A1%E3%81%8C%E6%AD%A3%E3%81%97%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B%E3%80%82%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AB%E3%81%9D%E3%81%AE%E7%AD%94%E3%81%88%E3%81%8C%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F%E3%81%AA%E3%82%89%E3%81%9D%E3%81%AE%E7%95%AA%E5%8F%B7%E3%82%82%E6%95%99%E3%81%88%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%95%E3%81%84%E3%80%82))</sub></sup>
>
> #### Answer
>
> 選ぶのはアビリティを使用する際になります。総合ルールに明記されていませんので、次の更新の際に追記いたします。ご指摘ありがとうございます。
>
> It will be when you use the ability to choose. Because not explicitly stated in the Comprehensive Rules, it will be appended to the time of the next update. Thank you for your advice. <sup><sub>([Auto-translated through Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/%E9%81%B8%E3%81%B6%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AF%E3%82%A2%E3%83%93%E3%83%AA%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E9%9A%9B%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%80%82%E7%B7%8F%E5%90%88%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AB%E6%98%8E%E8%A8%98%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7%E3%80%81%E6%AC%A1%E3%81%AE%E6%9B%B4%E6%96%B0%E3%81%AE%E9%9A%9B%E3%81%AB%E8%BF%BD%E8%A8%98%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%80%82%E3%81%94%E6%8C%87%E6%91%98%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A8%E3%81%86%E3%81%94%E3%81%96%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%80%82))</sub></sup>

In other words, targets are chosen when the card is used. It has not been added to the comprehensive rules by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, my Japanese isn't good enough to make sense of [the rules](http://www.square-enix-shop.com/jp/ff-tcg/rules/pdf/fftcg9.pdf). Google translate didn't provide a useable alternative. There is also a [rules guide](http://www.square-enix-shop.com/jp/ff-tcg/rules/ruleguide.html) to explain how to play the game that is less technical, and [individual card FAQs](http://www.square-enix-shop.com/jp/ff-tcg/rules/index.html).

From the rough translation Google provided, I gather that FInal Fantasy TCG plays very much like MtG. Spells/Abilities are anounnounced, costs are paid, and then the spell/ability is placed on the stack. Only after both players pass, does the top of the stack resolve. Since both players have the opportunity to react to the top of the stack, it is possible that the original targets may no longer be valid (if they changed zones).

[Wikia.com](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Final_Fantasy_Trading_Card_Game) says:

> To play a card or ability, **a player announces the card or ability and any targets it has then pays any costs for it**. Then, each other player may respond to that card or ability before it has its effect or enters the field, and the first player may respond to any actions the other players take. This is known as "the stack." Once players pass on playing cards or abilities, the objects on the stack resolve from top to bottom - in other words, first in, last out.